# Can I plug my standard phone into an ethernet jack?

Tags: ethernet, phone, cat5, rj-45

I just moved into a new house and it's wired for ethernet. There's a junction box that has a "Bridged Telecom Module TM-8" in it. My cable modem's phone jack is plugged into the "Line In" on that box and their are 8 slots all running to various ports in the house. All the jacks in the house are RJ45. Is there a way to plug my old phones into these jacks or do I need to upgrade to phones that use this connection?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can plug standard "square" RJ14 cables into a RJ45 jack, as long as the port is wired to your phone line. It should click in. You need to figure out which ports are wired where.

Answer (score 9):

As emddudley said, it should plug right in.  Just make sure you get the wiring correct.  Plugging a phone into a jack wired for ethernet probably won't be a problem.  Plugging a network device into a jack wired into the phone system is bad.  Phones ring by having a voltage sent down the line, enough to ring a physical bell on old [rotary phones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_500_telephone).  Network cards don't like getting this sent to them, and may release their [magic smoke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_smoke).