# Getting home prewired network jacks to work

Tags: home-networking

Thank you for any help

Moved into a new house and hooked up all my TVs, wireless internet, music, etc throughout the house, but i just dont understand how to get the wired ethernet jacks working. 
Everything else i have gotten to work.  Sorry its kind of a mess

Here are some pictures. Ive tried plugging a cord from the switch to everything i could think of in the patch panel/box whatever its called, but nothing i do seems to work.  Any suggestions?  Thank you

Heres pics of whatevers in the room

https://ibb.co/XJq0cLs
https://ibb.co/4FDGHk8
https://ibb.co/GRvqQyq
https://ibb.co/KzJP77T
https://ibb.co/xfMhThy
https://ibb.co/xshTthY

Tried uploading pics to the servers. First it told me they were too big. Resized them and then it told me i didnt have enough points to upload them

Comment: Your question will become far less useful to future visitors when the images you've linked are no longer accessible (which will eventually happen with off-site hosting). Please move all of these images to Stack Exchange's Imgur server. You can upload images to there using the image icon above the edit textarea when editing your post.

Comment: Those look suspiciously like they're set up to provide phone service and not ethernet...

Comment: O really?  What would i need to do to get the internet working.  It has 2 ethernet ports on each room and the house was built only 2 years ago so im assuming they must have had internet of some sort in mind with all of this

Comment: *"Everything else i have gotten to work"* versus *"nothing i do seems to work"* -- Sweeping generalizations that contradict each other provide zero net information.  Break your problem into two parts: (1) can you access the Internet (from somewhere/anywhere in the house), and (2) do you have a wired LAN in your house?

Comment: Sorry i meant to say the room had a ton of panels for cable/hdmi/sonos/speakers/ etc.  all of those seemed to be plug and play and work throughout the house.  My wireless internet is working (linksys velop with one in each room) but the speed is terrible in the far rooms (1000 down but lucky if i get 30 in the furthest bedrooms).  I guess im trying to get a wired LAN working here. Maybe im lost as to what to connect from the switch to the junction box to get all the wired ethernet ports in each room to work

Comment: Do you have landline phone service?  Try to identify the phone jack(s) in each room (@MichaelFrank 's concern) by plugging in a phone to every jack and listen for dial tone.  What's not a phone jack is then a possible Ethernet jack.  See https://superuser.com/questions/172654/can-i-plug-my-standard-phone-into-an-ethernet-jack

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing this setup, there's not much we can do except guess as to what you need to connect to make this work, and there are a couple things that I'm unsure of about your setup:

- The relative location of the patch panel and your internet termination point/modem
- How each port in the rooms are wired up since by the looks of the patch panel, they are sending a single 4-pair cable to each room and splitting it at the wall plate into 2x 2-pair connections.

With those out of the way, here's how I would troubleshoot this:

First off, I suggest picking up a cheap Network Cable Tester to verify continuity between the wall ports and the patch panel. This will make the following 100x easier to figure out.

Here is what I would do to get this to work:

- For testing purposes, unplug anything you have already patched to isolate the patch panels
- Start at the wall in a room you want internet access in
- Plug a network device in that will automatically attempt to make a connection when it sensing a network (computer, NAS, etc)
- Go to the patch panel and starting at 1, connect another Ethernet cable from the patch panel to your modem (or network switch)
- Check if a connection is made on the switch by checking the activity LEDs:

  - YES! Label it, and move on to the next port/room
  - No?! Try the next port on the patch panel

It might take a while, but you will have a much better idea of how your network has been installed by doing it this way.

Comment: Thank you very much i am going to try this this weekend!

Comment: Just want to say thank you.  I finally got back to the house today and this method work using an old switch i had!  Thank you again

Comment: @Chris916 Great to hear! Remember to accept an answer that works for you. :)

Answer (score 1):

You could build yourself a loopback with either a crimp tool or keystone jack and jumper and plug it into a jack in the house. You then plug a powered switch into each port until you find one that lights up the switch port.  Repeat until you know where most ports go.  Some jacks may be wired for phone or DSL so not all are necessarily working for ethernet.

Comment: Thanks i will try that next. I dont have any of that stuff yet unfortunately but i guess i will order it now

Comment: A running computer will light up a switch port just as well.  And the LAN ports of a router usually have individual lights the way a separate switch does so you can probably map the network with what you already have, just not as quickly because you'll be wandering around the house with a laptop.  Assuming you have enough equipment to make use of the cabling in the first place.  If your router or modem can't be located at the panel you are going to need a separate switch that can anyway.